# django translate variable content in template

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I'm using {% trans %} template tag. Django docs say:

> The {% trans %} template tag translates either a constant string (enclosed in single or double quotes) or variable content:

> > {% trans "This is the title." %}
> > {% trans myvar %}

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag

I found it impossible to do {% trans myvar %} because myvar simply doesn't show up in django.po file after running makemessages command.

Am I using it wrong? Could some help me with this?

Comment: Did you check fuzzy keywords in your editor ? While I was using Rosetta application as a translator, many keywords were kept as fuzzy.

Comment: It translates variable content as noted in one of the answers but you need to have that content translated in `django.po` file and compiled.

Answer (score 47):

You can use the [`blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans) template tag in this case:

```
{% blocktrans %} This is the title: {{ myvar }} {% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: But when I am using this blocktrans to translate database values, but in that case its not working, will you tell me solution, please  ?

Comment: I might be wrong. But you might have to write this way right? : {% bolcktrans myvar=myvar %}

Answer (score 33):

`{% trans myvar %}` just works. So check your PO file to make sure that the value of `myvar` is in PO msgid.

```
<title>{% trans myvar %}</title>
```

For example if `myvar` contains `"Some Publisher"` you can write the following in the PO file:

```
msgid "Some Publisher"
msgstr "কিছু প্রকাশক"
```

Also make sure you have ran:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Answer (score 13):

Django can't guess what is in that variable, so you have to translate it yourself by adding both the english (`msgid`) and the localized (`msgstr`) strings.

Comment: Do I need to specify the file and line number like this:#: templates/foo.html:45 msgid "myvar" msgstr "" ?

Comment: You don't _need_ too, because those are actually comments, but you might want to.

Comment: I have added msgid and msgstr in django.po and run compilemessages.But it doesn't seem to work. The varibles haven't been translated after changing locale. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have exactly this problem, however, django compilemessages comments out the msgid and msgstr I added. I find this answer very misleading.

Comment: It doesn't work to me either, i think database values brought to a template as {% blocktrans with aapptype=aapp.type %} {{ aapptype }} {% endblocktrans %} are not translated at all.

Comment: It worked great for me, just avoid running makemessages again, as those strings won't be found and will be commented.

Comment: And if you need to run makemessages again, just uncomment the translations you need afterwards.

Comment: Or create another dummy template file with all the different possible values of your variables, using {% trans "content" %}. In this way, makemessages will add them automatically to your django.po file. Not the most elegant solution but it works.

Comment: Shouldn't `noop` be used in this case? From the docs, `noop` creates a translation string in the po file, which is not directly used anywhere on the site. This way, you don't need to avoid running `makemessages`.

Answer (score 6):

My experience here is that variable translation **does not work in templates on its own**. However I came to a suitable solution when the content of the variables is known (I mean that they are not free text, but a set of choices you set in the database).

You need to **force the translation** in the view or in a filter tag.

To sum up:

1. Use `blocktrans` in your templates
2. Force variables to be translated

   - You either set variables in context that are already marked for transtalion
   - or use a filter to translate them
3. Generate translations in `.po` file

The story is like this:

**views.py**

```
def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'i18n_test.html', {'salutation':"Hola"})
```

**templates/i18n_test.html**

```
...
{% blocktrans %}{{ salutation }}{% endblocktrans %}
...
```

And when I render the template it always shows *Hola* whichever the current language is.

To force the translation, in the view we need to use ugettext.

```
def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'i18n_test.html', {'salutation':ugettext("Hola")})
```

However it is not always possible to access the view. So I prefer to use a filter like this.

**templatetags/i18n_extras.py**

```
@register.filter(name='translate')
def translate(text):
  try:    
    return ugettext(text)
```

And the template becomes

```
...
{% blocktrans s=salutation|translate %}{{ s }}{% endblocktrans %}
...
```

And produces *Hola, Hello, Ciao, Salut* depending on the current language.

The disadvantage (as pointed out in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation) ) is that `makemessages` does not automatically include these translations, so we need to include them manually. In django.po file:

**locales/en/django.po**

```
...
msgid "Hola"
msgstr "Hello"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the variable in the python code like here for `settings.SITE_NAME`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def processor004(request):
 my_dict = {
    'site_id004': settings.SITE_ID,
    'site_name004': _(settings.SITE_NAME),
    'installed_apps004': settings.INSTALLED_APPS,
    'embedded_widget004': settings.EMBEDDED_WIDGET,
    'base_template004': settings.BASE_TEMPLATE,
}

return my_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

make own tags

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

@register.simple_tag
def trans2(tr, *args, **kwargs):
    # print(':', kwargs)
    trans = _(tr)
    trans_str = trans.format(**kwargs)
    return trans_str
```

in template:

```
{% trans2 columns_once.res_data.message with value=columns_once.res_data.recommend%}
```

in django.po

```
#: default_content.py:136
msgid "_audit_recommend_speed"
msgstr "Рекомендованная скорость до {value} сек"
```

Answer (score 1):

As one workaround, you can collect `{% trans %}`(django 3.0 and below) or `{% translate %}`(django 3.1 and above) tags between `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` in one template. This will save your efforts to repeat typing the same msgid should you have more than one language po file.

```
{% comment %}
{% trans "Tea" %}
{% trans "Clothes" %}
{% endcomment %.}
```

Make sure you run `django-admin makemessages --all` after putting the aforementioned code.

Comment: doesn't seem to work though, every translatable string in the comment block was ignored

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex elegant solution that may help if you are translating values from model fields: http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org

"Modeltranslation

The modeltranslation application is used to translate dynamic content of existing Django models to an arbitrary number of languages without having to change the original model classes."

Answer (score 0):

To me, this happened when I had the `TEMPLATES.DIRS` outside my Django project directory. Fetching the templates into the project directory solved the problem.