# How to translate a variable with django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, gettext

I have a variable `my_variable` which can be onlye one of two values ("Swedish" or "English"). Then why can't I do this `{% trans "{{ my_variable|capfirst }}" %}` ? How should it be done? I want to translate the variable but it doesn't come out right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{%blocktrans%} This is the title: {{myvar}} {%endblocktrans%}
```

or

```
<title>{% trans myvar %}</title>
```

[django translate variable content in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546933/django-translate-variable-content-in-template)

Answer (score 3):

> Just use the `{% blocktrans %}` tag to include variable for translation.For more detailes[Follow this link with search blocktrans keyword.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/)

```
{% blocktrans with amount=article.price %}
That will cost $ {{ amount }}.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

> It may help you.Thank you.