# Django - how to manage variables inside a translation block?

Tags: python, django

I have the following paragraph at my django template I want to translate:

```
<p>Hello and welcome to {{ settings.SITE_NAME }}, nice to meet you</p>
```

How can I process the SITE_NAME variable at my .po file?

Comment: Hi, does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546933/django-translate-variable-content-in-template. And you could check this doc page https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code for `trans` and `blocktrans`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings, you can translate the SITE_NAME using:

```
gettext = lambda s: s
SITE_NAME = gettext('Anything')
```

And in template use blocktrans, example:

```
{% blocktrans with escaped_object=settings.SITE_NAME %}
Deleting the '{{ escaped_object }}' would result in deleting related objects.
{% endblocktrans %}
```